# Unable to access data of nested nodes of model object in template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have posted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/qgCp7/2/).
Here i am getting data of first node of `home_products` i.e.

```
    "contents": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "product_name": "abc11"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "product_name": "abc12"
        }
    ]
```

Failed to get data of second node i.e.

```
    "contents": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "product_name": "abc21"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "product_name": "abc22"
        }
    ]
```

every time i am getting same data i.e. data of first node.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FIXTURES` are wrongly nested, you should only have one `contents` array, resulting in:

```
Astcart.Application.FIXTURES=[
{
    "home_products": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Mobiles & Accessories",
            "contents": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "product_name": "abc11"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "product_name": "abc12"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "product_name": "abc21"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "product_name": "abc22"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "product_name": "abc31"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "product_name": "abc32"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qgCp7/3/).

Hope it helps.

### Update

It seams that the nested `contents` arrays inside each `home_product` need different `id`'s although they are in isolated arrays otherwise they get treated as one and overridden:

### Updated FIXTURES

```
Astcart.Application.FIXTURES = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Application 1",
    "home_products": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mobiles & Accessories",
        "contents": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "product_name": "abc11"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "product_name": "abc12"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "product_name": "abc21"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "product_name": "abc22"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "product_name": "abc31"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "product_name": "abc32"
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Bags & Cases",
        "contents": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "product_name": "def11"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "product_name": "def12"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "product_name": "def21"
            },
            {
                "id": "10",
                "product_name": "def22"
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "product_name": "def31"
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "product_name": "def32"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

### Udpated Index template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ol>
    {{#each application in model}}
      <li>{{application.name}}</li>
        <ul>
          {{#each homeproduct in application.home_products}}
            <li>{{homeproduct.name}}</li>
              <ul>
                {{#each item in homeproduct.contents}}
                  <li>{{item.product_name}}</li>
                {{/each}}
              </ul>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
  </ol>
</script>
```

[Updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/r9q9M/)

Comment: No,each node of "home_products" (in above fixture) contains array. How to work with this condition?

Comment: @user2625690, ah ok, let me make a different version, and I'll update my answer then...

Comment: Thanks, i am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @user2625690, there you have it, enjoy :)